# How to use INSERT INTO with a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-insert

I would appreciate if someone could help out.
There are two tables that I need to combine. So far I have been doing this every time.

```
  SELECT * INTO TABLE_3

  FROM TABLE_1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_2
    ON TABLE_1.[DATE] = TABLE_2.[DATE1]
```

However, I would like to skip the part of creating a new table and insert the columns I need directly into the existing table. 
I tried doing this,

```
INSERT INTO [TABLE_1] (USD,EUR,RUR)

SELECT USD,EUR,RUR 

FROM TABLE_1 AS T1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 AS T2
   ON T1.[DATE] = T2.[DATE1]
```

but got an error saying that my column names are ambiguous

I use SQL server 2014.

Comment: Just add aliases to column names like `T1.USD` etc.

Comment: Fully qualify the column names with the table alias e.g. T1.USD etc

Comment: @Serg please find the answer below

Comment: There is another column in table_1 called DPD which does not allow NULLS. When I add the aliases I get the error that this column cannot be NULL and the insert statement has been terminated. I don't really understand why this error occurs since I am not using that column for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving the column name directly, please specify the alias name to say from which table the column should take. May be here both tables having same column the you are trying to select. You should specify the exact table

```
INSERT INTO [TABLE_1] (USD,EUR,RUR)

SELECT [T1/T2].USD,[T1/T2].EUR,[T1/T2].RUR 

FROM TABLE_1 AS T1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 AS T2
   ON T1.[DATE] = T2.[DATE1]
```

Either you can specify T1 or T2 as per your business logic. Please rewrite the query as mentioned here. This will solve the problem. Please try this.